# HTTP POST file in pure sh + telnet : no curl, no wget

Tags: http, post, sh, telnet

I'm working on an old android device (wiko rainbow up 4G Android 5.1 if you wonder), and the only thing that truly works is telnet (the wget from busybox only have --post-data (no --post-file), curl seems not to be installable (I took severall hours trying to install it))

I'm trying to send screen.png over an http POST to an http server.

I got it working in pure telnet for small text or json files with the code below (took also some hours).

But when i went on bigger files, like a png image or an hexdump. this does not work.

I suspect this to be due by special characters present in the files. I think that may force telnet to quit

This problem is tricky, i'm stuck, but i hope one of you will like to get this challenge, to **http post png image over telnet**

Here is the sample server side code i use for testing :
https://gist.github.com/taterbase/2688850

```
FILE_TO_UPLOAD="./file.txt"
BOUNDARY=$((  RANDOM % 99999 ))
HOST="server.com"
POST_PATH="/upload.php"
FIELD_NAME="uploaded_file"
TLNET_CONTENT="-----------------------------$BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$FIELD_NAME\"; filename=\"$(basename $FILE_TO_UPLOAD)\"

$(cat $FILE_TO_UPLOAD)
-----------------------------$BOUNDARY--"
TLNET_HEADERS="POST $POST_PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: $HOST
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------$BOUNDARY
Content-Length: $(($(expr length "$TLNET_CONTENT") + 100 ))
Connection: keep-alive"

TELNET_ALL="$TLNET_HEADERS

$TLNET_CONTENT

"

telnet $HOST 80 <<AREALEOF
$TELNET_ALL
AREALEOF
```

Thank you, Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requires the request line, the headers lines, and the blank line separating the headers from the body to end with CR/LF pairs, not just a line feed.

```
FILE_TO_UPLOAD="./file.txt"
BOUNDARY=$((  RANDOM % 99999 ))
HOST="server.com"
POST_PATH="/upload.php"
FIELD_NAME="uploaded_file"

CONTENT=$(printf '%s\n' \
    "-----------------------------$BOUNDARY" \
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$FIELD_NAME\"; filename=\"$(basename $FILE_TO_UPLOAD)\""

   cat "$FILE_TO_UPLOAD"

   printf '%s\n' "-----------------------------$BOUNDARY--"
)

{
  printf '%s\r\n' \
    "POST $POST_PATH HTTP/1.1" \
    "Host: $HOST" \
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------$BOUNDARY" \
    "Content-Length: $(($(expr length "$CONTENT") + 100 ))" \
    "Connection: keep-alive" \
    "";

  printf '%s\n' "$CONTENT"
} | telnet $HOST 80
```

Comment: Was the `$(cat $FILE_TO_UPLOAD)` unnecessary ?

Comment: Sorry, it just got lost in the shuffle of getting rid of the variables.

Comment: As did the ability to specify the length of the content in the header; that's been restored as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to transfer the file. I used netcat.
If one day you are on a very limited system, it is very likely that you have at least netcat

On the reception side you have to execute
`nc -l -p 1234> out.file`

This will begin listening on port 1234 and store all in out.file
Pay attention to your firewall rules

On the sending side
`nc -w 3 [hostname / ip] 1234 <file_to_send.ext`

will allow you to send the file.

With that, i no longer needt to use TELNET.

However someone may find the others answers usefull.
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
I had to edit your suggestion to get it working on the android device but

```
FILE_TO_UPLOAD="./screen.png"
BOUNDARY=$((  RANDOM % 99999 ))
HOST="server.com"
POST_PATH="/upload.php"
FIELD_NAME="uploaded_file"

TLNET_CONTENT=$(printf '%s\n' \
    "-----------------------------$BOUNDARY" \
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$FIELD_NAME\"; filename=\"$(basename $FILE_TO_UPLOAD)\"" \
    "";
   cat "$FILE_TO_UPLOAD"
   printf '%s\n' "-----------------------------$BOUNDARY--"
)


{
    printf '%s\n' \
    "POST $POST_PATH HTTP/1.1" \
    "Host: $HOST" \
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------$BOUNDARY" \
    "Content-Length: $(($(expr length "$CONTENT") + 100 ))" \
    "Connection: keep-alive" \
    "";
    printf '%s\n' "$TLNET_CONTENT"
} | telnet $HOST 80
```

It still works for file.txt

However i still have many of these messages from the telnet, for png files does not work

```
    Console escape. Commands are:

     l      go to line mode
     c      go to character mode
     z      suspend telnet
     e      exit telnet
    continuing...

    Console escape. Commands are:

     l      go to line mode
     c      go to character mode
     z      suspend telnet
     e      exit telnet
    continuing...

    Console escape. Commands are:

     l      go to line mode
     c      go to character mode
     z      suspend telnet
     e      exit telnet
```